# "Source Not Found", Debugging Android Application in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, jar, android-source, platform

When I am trying to look at platform JAR or when I am debugging my android application in `Eclipse`, the following screen always show.

[image]

I have read some of the posts online and understand that **Android SDK** does not come with **Source Code**. But how can I download the correct version of source code and attach in Eclipse?

> I guess the following link provides the right solution for me, however, unfortunately it is outdated and I can download the source code for only **Cupcake(1.5)**, **Donut(1.6)** & **Eclair(2.1)**.

[Attaching Android platform source in Eclipse](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)

Can anyone provide me the link to download the source code for Ice Cream Sandwich(4.0.3)? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was solved by following a few steps below.

1) I downloaded the source code via Android SDK Manager. (The sources are downloaded to the **source directory** located in "path_to_android_sdk/sources/android-xx”). **xx** is the **API level number** (15 for 4.0.3). Android Versions and API Levels can be found in the following link for your convenience.

[Android Versions and API Levels](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html)

2) I zipped the downloaded file. (**android-15** in this case)

3) In **"Source Not Found"** page, I clicked "Attach Source" button and chose the zip file that I archived in step 2.

Comment: Simplification: You can also choose the folder, e.g. **android-15/**, when you click on "**Select folder...**" in the dialog that appears after clicking on "**Attach Source**". Maybe that's a new button?

Comment: @eWolf I am not sure. It could be a new button. Last time I can only attach zip files.

Answer (score 2):

For some time now, the Android SDK Manager allows you to install the sources for most SDK levels. Make sure your Android plugin for Eclipse is up to date. Start the SDK Manager and make sure you have the latest version of the tools. Then, under each SDK level, there should be an item titled *Sources for SDK*. Make sure that is installed for the level you want.

If the sources still are not available to the Eclipse debugger, right click on the project in the Package Explorer pane, navigate to Android Tools, and select "Fix Project Properties".

Answer (score 0):

The Android source tree is located in a Git repository hosted by Google. This document describes how to download the source tree for a specific Android code-line.

You can follow this link

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

and download the source code